# Testing ArangoDB Foxx app from CLI

Tags: arangodb, foxx

Currently, I'm running Mocha + Chai tests using Foxx web interface. It works well but I'd prefer to use Mocha's command line interface if that's possible. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to run the mocha tests from the mocha CLI as they have to run in the context of the installed Foxx service whereas mocha is run using Node.js (or theoretically one of the other supported environments).

You can run the tests of a Foxx service using the `foxx-manager` tool available on the machine on which ArangoDB is installed. We plan to eventually replace that tool with a node-based Foxx CLI you can run on any machine that has access to the database.

Comment: It's just not very convenient to click on buttons in a bunch of popups everytime I need to run tests. And web interface also lacks console output when testing. In my opinion, it would be better if there would be a page for running tests instead of a popup with terminal-like output

Comment: @artnikpro: do you mean having the tests as a separate tab in the web interface? Also, `foxx-manager` is a CLI tool, so that might be more to your liking.